# Integral of product of Bessel functions of the first kind

Tags: integration, special-functions

I would like to solve the integral:

$$\int_0^{+\infty}\quad rJ_n(ar)J_n(br)\quad dr$$

Is there any closed form for it?
Thanks!

What happens if I have instead:

$$\int_0^{c}\quad rJ_n(ar)J_n(br)\quad dr$$

with $c>0$.

(Since the first part has already a proper answer, the bounty is offered actually for the second part!)

Comment: What happens if the integration is done up to a constant $c$, instead of up to $+\infty$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [Wolfram functions](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/21/02/02/) (at the bottom) this is simply (for any $n$ in $\mathbb{R}$) :
$$\int_0^{+\infty}r\,J_n(ar)J_n(br)\ dr=\frac {\delta(a-b)}a$$

The same formula appears in [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/1.17#E13) where this closure equation appears with the constraints $\ \Re(n)>-1,\;a>0,\;b>0$ and additional references (A & W $11.59$ for example).

It may be proved using the Hankel transform : see [Wikipedia's 'Hankel transform'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform#Orthogonality).

---

If we replace the upper (infinite) bound by a finite bound $c$ we get the result kindly indicated by J.M. (changing merely the sign since we want the integral over $(0,c)$ and in conformity with Alpha's [result $\not =$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28x*besselJ%287,a*x%29*besselJ%287,b*x%29,x%29) and [result $=$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28x*besselJ%287,a*x%29*besselJ%287,a*x%29,x%29) for some specific value of $n$) :
\begin{align}
\tag{1}\int_0^c r\,J_n(a r) J_n(b r) \,dr&=\frac c{a^2-b^2}\left[b \;J_n(a\,c)\,J_{n-1}(b\,c)-a\;J_{n-1}(a\,c)\,J_n(b\,c)\right]\quad\text{if}\ a\not =b\\
\tag{2}\int_0^c r\,J_n(a r)^2 \,dr&=\frac {c^2}2\left[J_n(a\,c)^2-J_{n-1}(a\,c)\,J_{n+1}(a c)\right]\\
\end{align}

The first result appears as [entry $03.01.21.0064.01$](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/21/01/04/01/02/01/0004/) at Wolfram functions while the second is [entry $03.01.21.0055.01$](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/21/01/04/01/01/01/0004/). They are usually called 'first and second [Lommel integrals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LommelsIntegrals.html)'.

For a really venerable reference you may consult [Whittaker & Watson p.$381$](http://archive.org/details/ACourseOfModernAnalysis) with this interesting exercise (using our previous notations) :

"Shew that, if $a\not =b$ and $n>-1$",
$$(a^2-b^2)\int_0^c r\,J_n(a r) J_n(b r) \,dr=c\left[J_n(a\,c)\frac d{dc}J_n(b\,c)-J_n(b\,c)\frac d{dc}J_n(a\,c)\,\right],$$
$$2a^2\int_0^c r\,J_n(a r)^2 \,dr=(a^2c^2-n^2)J_n(a\,c)^2-\left[c\frac d{dc}J_n(a\,c)\right]^2$$

For a proof see [page $33$ and $34$ of Culham's lecture](http://www.mhtlab.uwaterloo.ca/courses/me755/web_chap4.pdf) or [Bowman's book page $101$](http://books.google.com/books?id=_k6iJN5QabUC&pg=PA101).

The recurrence relations ([Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_de_Bessel#Relation_avec_les_polyn.C3.B4mes_de_Laguerre)) :
$$\frac d{dc}J_n(a\,c)=\frac a2\left[J_{n-1}(a\,c)-J_{n+1}(a\,c)\right]= a\,J_{n-1}(a\,c)-\frac ncJ_n(a\,c)$$
should allow you to obtain the $(1)$ and $(2)$ formulas.

(the exercise $19$ from W & W with $a$ and $b$ two different zeros of $J_n$ seems of interest too)

---

[image: W & W]

Comment: Glad it helped @StefanoCoppola ! I added some references in the meantime that could interest you.

Comment: Gradshteyn/Ryzhik ought to have this as well...

Comment: Yes @J.M. : $6.512.8$ with the reference JAC $110$ (Jackson 'Classical Electrodynamics') but not in my fifth edition... :-)

Comment: From physical point of view, the delta function is rather clear: $J_{n}(ar)$ and $J_{n}(br)$ are eigenfunctions of the radial part of the 2D Laplacian (which is a symmetric operator) corresponding to differerent eigenvalues.

Comment: @O.L. From what I have read they should be interesting to develop Green functions in cylindrical coordinates but I must admit that I didn't use them this way yet... Most information was about [orthogonality relations](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22#E37) when the upper bound is finite. Thanks both for the information and attention in any way !

Comment: @Raymond Manzoni: My favorite way to look at classical special functions ($_2F_1$ and its degenerations) is to consider them as eigenfunctions of certain quantum mechanical problems. All basic properties (orthogonality relations, differentiation and recursion formulas, integral representations) then become very transparent.

Comment: @O.L. : In this case a challenging problem would be to study $\zeta$ and [random matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert–Pólya_conjecture) :-). Concerning QM I must admit that I appreciated the way Schiff introduced orthogonal polynomials neatly with generating functions. In QFT Feynman diagrams make heavy use of polylogarithms and [MZV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_zeta_function) as seen in Broadhurst's [papers](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9604128). They are linked too with knots and so on by Kreimer and Connes. All fascinating subjects !

Comment: @RaymondManzoni What if the integration is done up to a constant $c$ and not up to $+\infty$???

Comment: @JFNJr, you might be interested in this: $$\int_x^\infty r J_n(a r) J_n(b r) \,\mathrm dr=\frac{x}{a^2-b^2}(a J_{n-1}(a x) J_n(b x)-b J_n(a x) J_{n-1}(b x))$$

Comment: @J.M. Thanks! Is there any other way to express that difference of bessel functions??

Comment: @JFNJr, nothing simpler immediately comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and excellent answer @J.M. !

Comment: Something interesting happens when taking the limit as $c \rightarrow \infty$ for the Lommel integrals (equations 1 and 2). It does not result in $\int_{0}^{\infty} r J_n(ar) J_n(br) \text{d}r = \delta(a-b)/a$. Why is that?