# Definite integrals involving product of spherical bessel functions of the first kind

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

I'd like to solve the following integrals
$$\int_0^R |J_n(x)|^2 xdx$$
where $J_n(x)$ is the $n$-th order Bessel function of the first kind, and $R$ is a positive real constant.

$$\int_0^R |j_n(x)|^2x^2dx$$
where $j_n(x)$ is the $n$-th order spherical Bessel function of the first kind, and $R$ is a positive real constant.

Any ideas on how to tackle these problems?

Thanks a lot!

---

I find the first integral at [Integral of product of Bessel functions of the first kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393399/integral-of-product-of-bessel-functions-of-the-first-kind), so any ideas about the second integral?

Comment: Note that the integral in your reference is to infinity. You get a similar result for the spherical Bessel. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the identity $$j_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2x}}  J_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(x)$$
$$\int x^2 \,j_n(x){}^2 \,dx=\frac{\pi}{2} \int   x J_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(x){}^2 \,dx=\frac{\pi}{4}   x^2 \left(J_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(x){}^2-J_{n-\frac{1}{2}}(x)
   J_{n+\frac{3}{2}}(x)\right)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!