# Integral of product of Bessel functions of the first kind

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

I want to do this integral
$$U(k)=\int_{k'=0}^{\infty} F(k')\int_{r=0}^{c}J_0(k'r)J_0(kr)rdr k' dk'$$
where $J_0(x)$ is the 0th order Bessel function of the first kind, $F(x)$ is a function that I can compute numerically but don't know the explicit form.

I know
$$\mathrm{if} \quad c\rightarrow \infty,\qquad \mathrm{then} \quad U(k) = F(k)$$
by using the bessel function orthogonality
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}J_{m}(kr)J_{m}(k'r)rdr=\frac{1}{k}\delta(k-k') $$
What for a positive finite value $c$?

A maybe useful hint:[Integral of product of Bessel functions of the first kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393399/integral-of-product-of-bessel-functions-of-the-first-kind)

Comment: What is $F(k_1)$ ?

Comment: It would also be good if you could specify which variable corresponds to which integral. Also considering that you seem to want to integrate over $r,k_1,k_2$, three integral signs would be appropriate for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for advices, I've added more information about this question and change the text layout.